# Asterisk. Перенаправление на мобильный с сохранением CallerID

Tags: asterisk

Ситуация: Клиент А звонит на транк, по IVR передается на внутренний номер 101 (В), если абонента нет на рабочем месте и он не ответил в течение 40 секунд, срабатывает followme - происходит переадресация звонка на его мобильный 8926xxxxxxx. К нему приходит этот переадресованный звонок на мобильный с номером транка атс а не Клиента А. Какие должны быть настройки в транке для передачи CID (Клинента А) при переадресации на мобильный в Asterisk? Возможно ли это реализовать? Дело в том, что мы используем виртуальную АТС от "зелёного" ОПСоСа и там перенаправление идёт на мобильные сотрудников нашей организации с сохранением номера звонящего,
хотим от этого отказаться и перейти на свою АТС. (Freepbx, Sip trunk Мультифон)

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно уточнить у вашего оператора, поддерживает ли он звонки с установкой отличного от текущей линии CallerID. Либо искать для исходящих звонков другого оператора.